# cron не успевает выполнить скрипт по timeout

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Всем привет! 
А вы не подскажете, у меня в cron есть задача и она не успевает выполниться по timeout. 
Я использовал в задаче так `/usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 --timeout=360`, все равно минута получается на выполнение задачи.
Или тут влияет php.ini: `max_execution_time:60`?

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер позволяет в php можно использовать set_time_limit(0) - убирает ограничение на время работы скрипта.